# How to create digital signature

Tags: asp.net

Can someone tell me how to create digital signature with private and public keys in ASP.net?

Comment: You mean this? http://www.dotnetbips.com/articles/8e81f3f7-d850-44c9-a029-298607534bdf.aspx

Comment: You can go through the following link to create and verify the signature. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/06/25/how-to-sign-and-verify-the-signature-with-net-and-a-certificate-c.aspx?Redirected=true